# Why is my ExceptionMapper getting thrown away in Jersey/Grizzly?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, grizzly

Currently I'm working in Grizzly 2.3.16 and Jersey 2.14. I'm trying to get a custom exception handled by the server and returned to the client. Instead it seems I'm getting generic Grizzly errors, even though the correct code seems to be called.

This is the filter method (part of a class that has the '@Provider' decoration).

```
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) throws IOException 
{
    throw new MappableException(
        new CustomAuthenticationException(
            "Custom Error message"));
}
```

Here is the entire ExceptionMapper implementation:

```
@Provider
public class CustomAuthenticationExceptionMapper
    implements ExceptionMapper<CustomAuthenticationException>
{
    public Response toResponse(CustomAuthenticationException e)
    {
        return Response.status(Status.UNAUTHORIZED.getStatusCode()).
                header("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"Custom\"").
                type("text/plain").entity(e.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

Here is how I get the response and read it:

```
response = invocationBuilder.method(requestMethod.toString(), Response.class);
System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
```

When I get the entity, it's HTML from Grizzly as opposed to my custom message as it should be.

Here is the stack trace from just before toResponse is called - I can verify the code is being called but it looks like somehow Jersey or Grizzly is just discarding it and ultimately being replaced with the default grizzly message.

```
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.mapException(ServerRuntime.java:528)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:409)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1030)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:377)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.FilterChainImpl.invokeFilterChain(FilterChainImpl.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.doServletService(ServletHandler.java:221)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.service(ServletHandler.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm not sure what other parts would be relevant but they can be provided as necessary.

Comment: can you pls. create a testcase (on github?) to reproduce the problem?

Comment: you're throwing MappableException while your ExceptionMapper handles CustomAuthenticationException - this is probably the reason (unless CustomAuthenticationException  is a subtype of MappableException)

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add the jersey-grizzly-connector.jar from maven.